# How can I access the internal members from a different module in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, visibility, internals

In Kotlin when applying "internal" to the member function of a public class, it is only visible inside the module.

In the case that there are core modules, and another module (call it outermodule) which has a class derived from the class defined in the core module.

#### Core module

```
package com.core

class BaseClass {
   internal fun method_internal() {...}
   public fun method_public() {...}
}
```

In the core module, the `method_internal()` can be accessed outside the `BaseClass`.

In the app, whoever has dependency on the core module, the `BaseClass` can be used in the app, but in the app it cannot see the internal `method_internal()`. That is the `internal` behavior wanted.

In another module (the outermodule) it has a class which is derived from the `BaseClass`.

#### *outermodule*

```
package com.outermodule

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
......
}
```

In the outermodule it can use the `method_public()` from DerivedClass, but it can't access the `method_internal()`.

And it cannot make the `method_internal` as `protected` since it should allow access in everywhere in the core module.

How can I make the method have `internal` visibility in one module, but at least be able to accessed from derived classes in other modules?

Comment: You could make another method in the base class that is ```public``` that accepts a key as an argument in order to run the ```method_internal```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn’t pretty, but you can create two functions.

```
open class BaseClass {
    protected fun foo() {
        println("foo!")
    }

    internal fun fooInternal() = foo()

}
```